# K8S - Ingress - Route 2 different applications

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

In my minikube k8s cluster, I have 2 applications/services.

This is my ingress controller for the services I have.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-tutorial
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: default-http-backend
    servicePort: 80
  rules:
  - host: mysite.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /sva
        backend:
          serviceName: app-a
          servicePort: 8080
      - path: /svb
        backend:
          serviceName: app-b
          servicePort: 8150
```

When i type `mysite.com/sva` or `mysite.com/svb` it routes to appropriate services. However, none of the static files `(js, css, images etc)` is loaded as they seem to request for the resources from `mysite.com` instead of `mysite.com/sva/`

How can I make it look for the resources under specific service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on Harsh Manvar answer, Looks like rewrite does not work on the static resources as of now.

This is a workaround I am planning to follow to route diff apps like `sva.mysite.com` or `svb.mysite.com`. It works fine. Just adding this as an answer if somebody faces similar problem.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-tutorial
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: default-http-backend
    servicePort: 80
  rules:
  - host: sva.mysite.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: app-a
          servicePort: 8080
  - host: svb.mysite.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: app-b
          servicePort: 8150
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to Add the following annotation in ingress

> ingress.kubernetes.io/add-base-url: "true"

will solves this problem.

You can also review : https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/333

Comment: Thanks Harsh. But it does not help. I also tried by `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/add-base-url: "true"`

Comment: can you remove rewrite and try again please

Comment: I get 404 Not Found

Comment: thta's sounds weird not working ...ceheck this https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/333

Comment: ahhh... Thanks for sharing that. looks like a known issue - "“rewirte” does not work on resources."